# Loop through folders in linux?

Tags: linux

I want to move files from one directory to another

```
find /data/1990 -name "*.dat" -exec mv {} /data1/1990/ \;
```

that was easy. 
noW I have in /data/ many years 1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995

How to loop over these years?

Comment: Do you have subfolders under your years? If not, then `find` is overkill. You can just use `mv`.

Comment: Thanks what about the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
for i in `ls /data/`; 
do 
    echo "element=$i";  #put your code for each element
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd make my life easier by changing my current working directory:

```
cd /data
find 199[012345] -name "*.dat" -exec echo mv {} /data1/{} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us what shell are you using (and they differ just like programming languages do). But in bash or zsh, to provide year range you can use curly brackets, ie:

```
for year in {1990..1995}; do
    find /data/$year -name "*.dat" -exec mv {} /data1/$year \;
done
```

You can also use arithmetic evaluation and more modern(?) block syntax:

```
for ((year=1990; year<1995; year++)) {
    find /data/$year -name "*.dat" -exec mv {} /data1/$year \;
}
```